# Does the speed of ldp instruction depend on caching?

Tags: arm64, perf

I created an annotated trace with perf. For some reason, the instructions with the highest percentages are of type ldp:

```
  5.56 │       ldp    s9, s8, [x28,#80] 
 37.65 │       ldp    s2, s3, [x19,#24]
 37.65 │       ldp    s2, s3, [x19,#24]
```

Is this a mistake? Or does it hint toward bad L1/L2 caching because ldp sped depends on cache?

Edit:

Here is an excerpt from an annotated output of perf. The excerpt is from a glm matrix multiplication my function uses:

```
       │     _ZN3glmmlIdLNS_9precisionE0EEENS_7tmat4x4IT_XT0_EE8row_typeERKNS4_8col_typeERKS4_():                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ▒
       │        )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ▒
       │        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ▒                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ▒
       │                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
       │           return typename tmat4x4<T, P>::row_type(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ◆
       │              m[0][0] * v[0] + m[0][1] * v[1] + m[0][2] * v[2] + m[0][3] * v[3],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
 28.86 │ 40:   ldp    d3, d0, [x0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ▒
       │       add    x4, x4, #0x20                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ▒
       │       ldp    d18, d10, [x1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ▒
       │              m[1][0] * v[0] + m[1][1] * v[1] + m[1][2] * v[2] + m[1][3] * v[3],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
  0.34 │       ldp    d21, d24, [x1,#32]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
       │              m[2][0] * v[0] + m[2][1] * v[1] + m[2][2] * v[2] + m[2][3] * v[3],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
  0.34 │       ldp    d20, d23, [x1,#64]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
       │              m[3][0] * v[0] + m[3][1] * v[1] + m[3][2] * v[2] + m[3][3] * v[3]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ▒
  0.34 │       ldp    d19, d22, [x1,#96]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
       │              m[1][0] * v[0] + m[1][1] * v[1] + m[1][2] * v[2] + m[1][3] * v[3],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
       │       fmul   d24, d0, d24                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ▒
       │              m[0][0] * v[0] + m[0][1] * v[1] + m[0][2] * v[2] + m[0][3] * v[3],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
 10.07 │       ldp    d2, d1, [x0,#16]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ▒
       │              m[2][0] * v[0] + m[2][1] * v[1] + m[2][2] * v[2] + m[2][3] * v[3],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
       │       fmul   d23, d0, d23                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ▒
       │              m[3][0] * v[0] + m[3][1] * v[1] + m[3][2] * v[2] + m[3][3] * v[3]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ▒
  0.34 │       ldp    d8, d6, [x1,#16]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ▒
       │       fmul   d22, d0, d22                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ▒
  0.34 │       ldp    d17, d7, [x1,#48]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ▒
       │              m[0][0] * v[0] + m[0][1] * v[1] + m[0][2] * v[2] + m[0][3] * v[3],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
       │       fmul   d0, d0, d10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ▒
       │              m[3][0] * v[0] + m[3][1] * v[1] + m[3][2] * v[2] + m[3][3] * v[3]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ▒
       │       ldp    d16, d5, [x1,#80]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ▒
       │              m[1][0] * v[0] + m[1][1] * v[1] + m[1][2] * v[2] + m[1][3] * v[3],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
       │       fmadd  d21, d3, d21, d24                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ▒
       │              m[3][0] * v[0] + m[3][1] * v[1] + m[3][2] * v[2] + m[3][3] * v[3]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ▒
  0.34 │       ldp    d9, d4, [x1,#112]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ▒
       │              m[2][0] * v[0] + m[2][1] * v[1] + m[2][2] * v[2] + m[2][3] * v[3],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
       │       fmadd  d20, d3, d20, d23                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ▒
       │              m[3][0] * v[0] + m[3][1] * v[1] + m[3][2] * v[2] + m[3][3] * v[3]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ▒
       │       fmadd  d19, d3, d19, d22                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ▒
       │              m[0][0] * v[0] + m[0][1] * v[1] + m[0][2] * v[2] + m[0][3] * v[3],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
       │       fmadd  d0, d18, d3, d0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ▒
       │              m[1][0] * v[0] + m[1][1] * v[1] + m[1][2] * v[2] + m[1][3] * v[3],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
  0.67 │       fmadd  d17, d2, d17, d21                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ▒
       │              m[2][0] * v[0] + m[2][1] * v[1] + m[2][2] * v[2] + m[2][3] * v[3],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
       │       fmadd  d16, d2, d16, d20                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ▒
       │              m[3][0] * v[0] + m[3][1] * v[1] + m[3][2] * v[2] + m[3][3] * v[3]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ▒
       │       fmadd  d7, d1, d7, d17                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ▒
       │       fmadd  d5, d1, d5, d16                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ▒
  1.01 │       fmadd  d9, d2, d9, d19                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ▒
       │              m[0][0] * v[0] + m[0][1] * v[1] + m[0][2] * v[2] + m[0][3] * v[3],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
       │       fmadd  d2, d8, d2, d0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ▒
       │              m[3][0] * v[0] + m[3][1] * v[1] + m[3][2] * v[2] + m[3][3] * v[3]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ▒
       │       fmadd  d4, d1, d4, d9                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ▒
       │       fmadd  d1, d6, d1, d2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ▒
  0.67 │       add    x0, x0, #0x20
```

Regards

Edit: I added the sourcecode of the current version of the method that produces ~2500 cache misses on 10000 input elements. Maybe someone has still ideas:

```
inline void
transformVector ( glm::mat4 const & matrix,
                  std::vector < glm::vec4 > const & input,
                  std::vector < glm::vec4 >       & output )
{
   float32x4x4_t iMatrix = *(float32x4x4_t *)&matrix;
   float32x4_t rslt;

   std::vector < glm::vec4 >::const_iterator inVertexStart  = input.begin();
   std::vector < glm::vec4 >::const_iterator inVertexEnd    = input.end();
   std::vector < glm::vec4 >::iterator       outVertexStart = output.begin();

   for ( ; inVertexStart != inVertexEnd; inVertexStart++, outVertexStart++ )
   {
      const float32x4_t input_local = *( float32x4_t const * )&(*inVertexStart);
      rslt = vmulq_f32(      iMatrix.val[0], input_local);
      rslt = vmlaq_f32(rslt, iMatrix.val[1], input_local);
      rslt = vmlaq_f32(rslt, iMatrix.val[2], input_local);
      rslt = vmlaq_f32(rslt, iMatrix.val[3], input_local);

      vst1q_f32( (float32_t*)&( *outVertexStart ), rslt);
   }
}
```

ASM:

```
0x0000000000400fb0 <+0>:    ldr x3, [x1,#8]
0x0000000000400fb4 <+4>:    ldr x1, [x1]
0x0000000000400fb8 <+8>:    ldr q5, [x0]
0x0000000000400fbc <+12>:   cmp x1, x3
0x0000000000400fc0 <+16>:   ldr q4, [x0,#16]
0x0000000000400fc4 <+20>:   ldr q3, [x0,#32]
0x0000000000400fc8 <+24>:   ldr q2, [x0,#48]
0x0000000000400fcc <+28>:   ldr x2, [x2]
0x0000000000400fd0 <+32>:   b.eq    0x400ff4 <transformVector(glm::tmat4x4<float, (glm::precision)0> const&, std::vector<glm::tvec4<float, (glm::precision)0>, std::allocator<glm::tvec4<float, (glm::precision)0> > > const&, std::vector<glm::tvec4<float, (glm::precision)0>, std::allocator<glm::tvec4<float, (glm::precision)0> > >&)+68>
0x0000000000400fd4 <+36>:   ldr q1, [x1],#16
0x0000000000400fd8 <+40>:   fmul    v0.4s, v1.4s, v4.4s
0x0000000000400fdc <+44>:   cmp x3, x1
0x0000000000400fe0 <+48>:   fmla    v0.4s, v1.4s, v5.4s
0x0000000000400fe4 <+52>:   fmla    v0.4s, v3.4s, v1.4s
0x0000000000400fe8 <+56>:   fmla    v0.4s, v1.4s, v2.4s
0x0000000000400fec <+60>:   str q0, [x2],#16
0x0000000000400ff0 <+64>:   b.ne    0x400fd4 <transformVector(glm::tmat4x4<float, (glm::precision)0> const&, std::vector<glm::tvec4<float, (glm::precision)0>, std::allocator<glm::tvec4<float, (glm::precision)0> > > const&, std::vector<glm::tvec4<float, (glm::precision)0>, std::allocator<glm::tvec4<float, (glm::precision)0> > >&)+36>
0x0000000000400ff4 <+68>:   ret
```

Comment: re: your title question: yes of course it depends on cache hit/miss.  Whether perf samples line up exactly with the instruction that caused the miss is another question.  e.g. on out-of-order execution x86, it's common to get sample on the instruction that *consumes the result* of a slow instruction (like a division or a load that often misses in cache).

Comment: Do you really have two back-to-back `ldp` instructions with the same address and the same target registers, that both happened to get the exact same fraction of perf samples?  Is there no surrounding code that's maybe slow to calculate the `x19` address register input to `ldp`?

Comment: What hardware are you profiling on?  In-order or out-of-order being the main question, but cortex-?? or some other AArch64 or what?  If you profile for a different event, like cache misses, do you get more hits on those instructions?

Comment: The hardware is a Cortex A57. No, the instructions are not back to back. They are scattered across the function I'm interested in. There is some stuff that is supposedly more expensive ( sorts, matrix multiplications etc.) but also highly cache efficient. I haven't profiled for cache misses yet.

Comment: ALU work will probably tend to spread the counts out over multiple instructions, while a load that frequently misses in cache will get all the counts itself, if the performance-counter hardware charges the `ldp` with the cycles.  That does make sense if the cache-miss load becomes the oldest instruction in the ROB and stalls allocation of new instructions for OoO exec, since A57 is an out-of-order core.  But >70% of the total counts for just two loads is really high.  Are those percentages of the *total*, or percentages of the counts within separate functions?

Comment: https://www.tomshardware.co.uk/arm-cortex-a72-architecture,review-33404.html#p3 compares A72 vs. A57, and says A57 has a 128-entry reorder buffer (same as A72).  That's pretty respectable; as large as Intel [Nehalem](https://www.realworldtech.com/nehalem/6/) (and much larger than Intel's low-power Silvermont.)  So depending on memory latency and clock speed, a 128-entry ROB is big enough to hide a significant amount of memory latency, but probably still not a full cache miss.  And not if it's part of a longer dependency chain.

Comment: The percentage is over a function. The large ones are inside loops. I built a test where a matrix multiplication is performed over a std::vector < glm::vec4 > with 10.000 loop entries. Using callgrind and kcachegrind, 2500 cache misses were determined. Which shouldn't be a coincidence: 4 * sizeof(glm::vec4) is 64 byte, the L1 cache line size of a Cortex A57. I have the feeling the cpu doesn't do much prefetching.

Comment: In your matmul, are you striding down one whole column without cache-blocking aka loop tiling?  That could certainly explain it.  A cache-aware matmul can generally get mostly L1d hits.  Even if you use all 4 SIMD vectors of a cache line before moving on (AArch64 has 32 vector regs, so it shouldn't be a problem to be doing 4 vectors in parallel), that's still a tough access pattern for a HW prefetcher to lock on to.  Especially if the stride is large and typically crosses 4k page boundaries.

Comment: I added the current sourcecode of the method. Maybe you have some ideas.

Comment: The matrix should be column-oriented. Since we get ~2500 cache misses on 10000 elements I assume that he loads one 64-byte cacheline ( sizeof( glm::vec4 ) * 4 ) and never prefetches more than one chacheline. Or that the multiplications themselves are so fast that prefetching more than one cacheline does not help.